# Very coarse spatial resolution (>1000m) global digital elevation raster data

Tags: data-request, download

I am searching for very coarse spatial resolution (>1000m pixel size) digital elevation model (DEM) global raster data. I am aware of data sources like SRTM or Copernicus DEM (90m pixel size) but unfortunately it will be very difficult to download a global DEM with such resolution. Do you know any sources from where I can, freely, download very coarse spatial resolution DEM data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be using R and download prepared set like:

```
r <- geodata::elevation_global(res = 10, path = "data")
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1080, 2160, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#> source      : wc2.1_10m_elev.tif 
#> name        : wc2.1_10m_elev 
#> min value   :           -352 
#> max value   :           6251

terra::plot(r)
```

[image]

The parameter `res` corresponds to desired resolution: 10, 5, 2.5, and 0.5 minutes of a degree. The data itself comes from UC Davis https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/climate/worldclim/2_1/base/wc2.1_10m_elev.zip

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I wasn't aware of the package `geodata`. Good solution.